# docker service create error: library BIO_new_file No such file or directory crypto/bio/bss_file c67 calling fopen when use certbot to create ssl cert

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, certbot, letsencrypt

I use the below script to create an SSL certificate for my website which is hosted in VPS with dockerized nginx webserver. It's got the certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -x "$(command -v docker compose)" ]; then
  echo 'Error: docker compose is not installed.' >&2
  exit 1
fi

domains=(example.com api.example.com)
rsa_key_size=4096
data_path="./certbot"
email="example.com@gmail.com" # Adding a valid address is strongly recommended
staging=0 # Set to 1 if you're testing your setup to avoid hitting request limits

if [ -d "$data_path" ]; then
  read -p "Existing data found for $domains. Continue and replace existing certificate? (y/N) " decision
  if [ "$decision" != "Y" ] && [ "$decision" != "y" ]; then
    exit
  fi
fi


if [ ! -e "$data_path/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf" ] || [ ! -e "$data_path/conf/ssl-dhparams.pem" ]; then
  echo "### Downloading recommended TLS parameters ..."
  mkdir -p "$data_path/conf"
  curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot-nginx/certbot_nginx/_internal/tls_configs/options-ssl-nginx.conf > "$data_path/conf/options-ssl-nginx.conf"
  curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/certbot/certbot/master/certbot/certbot/ssl-dhparams.pem > "$data_path/conf/ssl-dhparams.pem"
  echo
fi

echo "### Creating dummy certificate for $domains ..."
path="/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domains"
mkdir -p "$data_path/conf/live/$domains"
docker service create --with-registry-auth -d --entrypoint "\
  openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:$rsa_key_size -days 1\
    -keyout '$path/privkey.pem' \
    -out '$path/fullchain.pem' \
    -subj '/CN=localhost'" certbot/certbot
echo


echo "### Starting nginx ..."
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml exampleApp
echo

echo "### Deleting dummy certificate for $domains ..."
docker service create --with-registry-auth -d --entrypoint "\
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domains && \
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/$domains && \
  rm -Rf /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/$domains.conf" certbot/certbot
echo


echo "### Requesting Let's Encrypt certificate for $domains ..."
#Join $domains to -d args
domain_args=""
for domain in "${domains[@]}"; do
  domain_args="$domain_args -d $domain"
done

# Select appropriate email arg
case "$email" in
  "") email_arg="--register-unsafely-without-email" ;;
  *) email_arg="--email $email" ;;
esac

# Enable staging mode if needed
if [ $staging != "0" ]; then staging_arg="--staging"; fi

docker service create --with-registry-auth -d --entrypoint "\
  certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot \
    $staging_arg \
    $email_arg \
    $domain_args \
    --rsa-key-size $rsa_key_size \
    --agree-tos \
    --force-renewal" certbot/certbot
echo

echo "### Reloading nginx ..."
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml exampleApp
```

The `docker service create` lines raise this error and can't work correctly.

```
library:BIO_new_file:No such file or directory:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:67:calling fopen
```

I use the below command instead of `docker service create`, However, It still gives the same error.

```
docker compose run --rm --entrypoint "\
  openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:$rsa_key_size -days 1\
    -keyout 'privkey.pem' \
    -out 'fullchain.pem' \
    -subj '/CN=localhost'" certbot/certbot
```

What's the problem?

Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Nginx image: stable-alpine
Certbot image: certbot:latest